# how to add footer in center using css class

Tags: html

I am trying to set a footer in center but not work

```
<style>
    .footer {
        color: Black;
        margin-top: 150px;
        align-content:center;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
   <div class="top-row footer">
        CopyRight@CCX.Com
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I am using html with css class

I want to footer in center

Edit:

after adding `text-align: center;`  not set the footer in center see below image

[image]

Comment: text-align: center;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Comment: @Sagar when I add text align center than background effect also cut

Comment: @FluffyKitten  why give -3 point that is not issue I would suggest give more and more -1 when problem is small
   but I add ```text-align: center;``` also not work see my edit question I already try I know this is small thing but I am not able to solve that is reason I am coming here

Comment: `text-align` works with the code in your question. If that didn't work in your project then the problem is with something else. You need to do some debugging to find that code and give it to us so so we can help. We can only help you fix the problem in the code you give us - we have no idea what else you might have, we're not mind readers!  Also, *I* didn't give you -3 votes! At a guess, the downvotes were for lack of effort and research - the question you have asked has been asked many times before. You say you tried but there is no evidence of that in your question.

Comment: can you create codesandbox link ?

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit your question to add the relevant code - preferably in a Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` button in the question editor, so that we can run the code directly in your question.

Comment: @FluffyKitten sorry sir ok thanks for your suggestion I will find the solution and debugger in console log what is the issue thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.

```
<style>
    .footer {
        color: Black;
        margin-top: 150px;
        text-align: center; // <---
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
   <div class="top-row footer">
        CopyRight@CCX.Com
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your contributions are welcome, but please note that answering questions that already have good answers on the site (like this one) like discouraged. Please see the "Answer well-asked questions" section in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Instead you should flag duplicate questions when you have enough rep, or comment with a link to the duplicate. Or simply just move on to well-asked questions :)